# matrix norm derivative with respect a parameter

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, differential

What is the result of the following expression
$\frac{d}{dt}\left( \|A(t)-B(t) \|\right) $, where $\|\cdot \|$ can be for instance the Frobenius norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = \langle X(t),X(t) \rangle $, where $X(t) = A(t)-B(t)$ and $\langle C,D \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(C^T D)$.

Then we have $\phi'(t) = 2 \langle X'(t),X(t) \rangle  = 2\langle A'(t)-B'(t),A(t)-B(t) \rangle $.

Since $\eta(t)= \|A(t)-B(t)\| = \sqrt{\phi(t)}$, we have 
$\eta'(t) = {\operatorname{tr} ((A'(t)-B'(t))^T(A(t)-B(t)) ) \over \|A(t)-B(t)\|} $ (assuming $A(t) \neq B(t)$).

Comment: do you think it can be generalized to general norm?

Comment: @Bob: I doubt it. A norm is not necessarily differentiable (it is differentiable ae. [$m$] by the Rademacher theorem), so the best you could hope for would be something involving subdifferentials (my opinion).

Comment: I have just noticed that it should be :$\phi'(t)=2Re\langle X'(t),X(t)\rangle$. Right?

Comment: @Bob: Yes, I had assumed that $A,B$ were real valued.